# Rails ActiveRecord Session Store in HTML5 SessionStorage Instead of Cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, session, activerecord, session-storage

My application has a requirement for users to log into different accounts in separate tabs in their browser (we target Chrome specifically). Because Rails uses cookies to store session info, when the user is logged in, they are logged in on all tabs in the browser. I'm using the ActiveRecord session store method, but even the ID for the session is saved as a cookie.

It seems there's a solution in using HTML5's sessionStorage mechanism, which is limited in scope to the tab or window that the user is logged into. It seems all I have to do is direct Rails to save the session info into the sessionStorage rather than cookies. But I can find no information on this at all.

Assuming there's no way to configure the session store to do this in Rails, is it possible to override the ActiveRecord session saving mechanism? Any pointers on where to look for info about how to go about this?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike cookies, sessionStorage entries cannot be created with response headers, and are not automatically included in request headers. This puts a lot of the workload for managing sessionStorage/localStorage-based authentication on client-side Javascript. All authenticated access would have to be through Javascript XHR requests which explicitly include the authentication token.

If you want the user to be able to have several concurrent sessions, and you don't want to build your site as a [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), then you will have to take an alternate approach with cookies.

One way would be to use multiple domains to force the cookies into separate subspaces. Set a wildcard DNS record and configure your web server to accept all matching requests regardless of prefix. For example, users might by default be at `www.yoursite.com`. You would provide a 'create new session' link which opens a new tab to a random subdomain, e.g. `1234abcd.www.yoursite.com`. This may create a problem if you are using SSL, however; wildcard SSL certificates tend to be much more expensive.

A simpler way would be to educate users about their browsers' private/icognito modes, which maintain independent cookie stores. However, getting users to read documentation is always a challenge.

Answer (score -1):

You now configure the Cookie-based session store through an initializer, probably in **config/initializers/session_store.rb**. In Rails 3 the session store is a piece of middleware, and the configuration options are passed in with a single call to config.session_store:

**Your::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_session'**

You can put any extra options you want in the hash with :key, e.g.

```
Your::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, {
  :key =>           '_session_id',
  :path =>          '/',
  :domain =>        nil,
  :expire_after =>  nil,
  :secure =>        false,
  :httponly =>      true,
  :cookie_only =>   true
}
```

Comment: I am configuring the session store here and using the ActiveRecord session store. How would I manage this to save in the HTML5 sessionStorage instead of a cookie though?